# Recursive implementation of Euclid's Algorithm - Type Error

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

This is the code (Euclid's algorithm for GCD). Of course there is `Prelude.gcd` but as an exercise I am implementing my own.

```
selfGCD :: Integral f => f -> f -> f  
selfGCD a b = if b == 0 then
        return a
    else 
        return (selfGCD a (mod a b))
```

Using **ghci**, I get the following error:

```
two.hs:32:25:  
Couldn't match type `f' with `m0 f'  
  `f' is a rigid type variable bound by  
      the type signature for selfGCD :: Integral f => f -> f -> f  
      at two.hs:31:1  
In the return type of a call of `return'  
In the expression: return a  
In the expression:  
  if b == 0 then return a else return (selfGCD a (mod a b))  

two.hs:34:25:  
Couldn't match type `f' with `m1 f'  
  `f' is a rigid type variable bound by  
      the type signature for selfGCD :: Integral f => f -> f -> f  
      at two.hs:31:1  
In the return type of a call of `return'  
In the expression: return (selfGCD a (mod a b))  
In the expression:  
  if b == 0 then return a else return (selfGCD a (mod a b))
```

How can I rectify the problem?

Comment: Note there's an implementation error. Once the call to `return` is removed, `selfGCD a b` will always result in `a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Drop the `return`s.

In Haskell, `return` is a function of type

```
return :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

and not the `return` operator you know from imperative languages.

Thus with the `return`s, the implementation has type

```
selfGCD :: (Integral a, Monad m) => a -> a -> m a
```

contrary to the type signature.

Comment: Might want to mention that in Haskell there is no real distinction between a function and what it returns. A function returns a definition/a definition is a function. The name is merely a convenient label by which to refer to a definition; just like a named constant in imperative languages is merely a convenient label to refer to that constant value.

Comment: Why 11 minutes wait to accept it as correct? It is already correct (at least it is working as expected).

Comment: I think the logic there is to give at least a little bit of time for alternative answers as well as more comments and edits on the main answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't use `return`. In Haskell, it doesn't do what you think it does. Second of all, your arguments for calling gcd again are swapped. It should be selfGCD b (mod a b)

See the edited code below which works as expected of a GCD algorithm.

```
selfGCD :: Integral f => f -> f -> f  
selfGCD a b = if b == 0 then a else selfGCD b (mod a b)
```